# FreeOTP Two factor authentication in .Net Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, authorization, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication

How to set up two factor authentication in .Net application using FreeOTP?

I want to use two factor authentication during login or somewhere else like approvals etc. looking for the sample code or article which can guide me how to apply in application. thanks

here is the link for info about FreeOTP Authentication
https://freeotp.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

I'm also searching these days for a solution to integrate Google Authenticator and FreeOTP in ASP.NET Identity.

FreeOTP writes on their page (https://freeotp.github.io):

> FreeOTP implements open standards: HOTP and TOTP. This means that no proprietary server-side component is necessary

So you can use any free OTP nuget package - and you can serve both Google Authenticator and FreeOTP as well. For example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OtpSharp/

**Example for ASP.NET Identity 2.0**

I have found an example on the microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity#enabling-2fa) and they are referring there to an interesting tutorial:

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-google-authenticator-asp-net-identity/

In this tutorial they are using "OtpSharp" to integrate the google authenticator. It should work in the same way for FreeOTP (but I havn't tested it).

Comment: thanks provided detail is very useful! +1  i also found a sample [link](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-two-factor-authentication-using-google)

Comment: I have implemented this now in my project - it is working with Google Authenticator and FreeOTP (and also any app that supports TOTP, for example it also works with password managers - most of pw-manager have a browser plugin for autofilling credentials and they also copy the TOTP-Code automatically into the clipboard, so you can directly paste the code into the input field > very comfortable).

Comment: Basically you have only to follow the provided link for the google authenticator. I have made several changes especially for my application, so sharing code wouldn't be helpful. Just follow the link of my answer and you get everthing you need.

Comment: Thanks it is really helpful